# Visual Studio. Unable to start program '' The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Its my first program on Visual Studio on C#.
I did not write my own code and Im trying to open any template projects with simple console writes.

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}

// Run program: Ctrl + F5 or Debug > Start Without Debugging menu
// Debug program: F5 or Debug > Start Debugging menu

// Tips for Getting Started: 
//   1. Use the Solution Explorer window to add/manage files
//   2. Use the Team Explorer window to connect to source control
//   3. Use the Output window to see build output and other messages
//   4. Use the Error List window to view errors
//   5. Go to Project > Add New Item to create new code files, or Project > Add Existing Item to add existing code files to the project
//   6. In the future, to open this project again, go to File > Open > Project and select the .sln file
```

However Im receiving error that I do not know how to solve.

**Errors:**
Unable to build properly.
When I try to build, there are tons of errors
eg 
cannot open source file ... (tons of this)
the global scope has no .... (tons of this)

And when I try to run, obviously it wont run. It will tell me
"Unable to start program. 'C:\repo....\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe' The system cannot find the file specified."


*This is my very first program and Im unable to run it. I believe its probably due to file path of the project - unable to find the appropriate files. I have no idea which setting to tweak as well... Probably a very simple solution but I cant find it online. Thanks.*

Comment: Someone changed your tag, but the question still says C#. The most important thing when beginning programming is learning what language you are using, because each one has differences. In this case, your example code is **C++**, *not* **C#**. If your intention is to work with C#, you need different code. Otherwise, you need to update your question with details showing the error messages, etc. See [ask].

Comment: Sorry, it should be C++

Comment: Not an answer because it's just a guess, but I'm giving an 90% chance that the issue is that you didn't fully install the "Desktop Development with C++" (or something like that) workload of Visual Studio.

Comment: As a note for future questions, **never** paraphrase the build errors. At most, edit paths that appear to remove sensitive information, but for C++ error messages, the exact wording is important, and as a beginner, you generally don't know which of the possibly dozens of messages is the relevant one. For code that is more than 5 lines long, you should also note the line numbers of the error messages show clearly what code line they refer to in whatever snippet you post.

Answer (score 0):

According to your example code, this is a C ++ project and not a C # project. If you want to create a C# project ,you need different code.

If you created a c++ project, and got this error. I sugges you could follow the following steps to resolve the issue:

1,You should build the project before running it.

The cause of this error is most likely because you haven't built your project from **Build > Build Solution**. The reason you're getting this error when you try to run your project is because Visual Studio can't find the executable file that should be produced when you build your project.

2,Check if the linker output file matches the path, name and extension of the target file.

**Right Click Project Name > Properties -> Linker > General -> Output File > $(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Assuming im building a c++ project, 
i tried to Build > Build Solution, but same errors appear, there is a bunch of errors regarding "cannot open source file..." & "the global scope has no..."

Comment: I suggest you should provide us more information for the error, we will provide you with better help.

Answer (score -1):

Simply Run the project in Visual Studio 2022

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).